# Silent Installation in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

It is work correctly but, it's asking Do you allow following program from an unknow publisher to make changes to this computer. Yes or No I don't want this directly when i click on install button it will install on my system.

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Install software
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
          //  p.StartInfo.FileName = txtname.Text;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/qb /i \"{0}\" ALLUSERS=1", @"C:\Users\d.soni\Desktop\setup.msi");
            //process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/qb /i \"{0}\" ALLUSERS=1", @"E:\Setup.msi");
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();

        }
```

Comment: So... you wan't to disable a security measure?  Why would you want to do that?

Comment: i create control panel . as a requirement of client i have to do that.

Comment: @EdS. If you know please reply. Or it possible or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a normal Windows behavior. When trying to install something on a computer and you are logged in as administrator it will prompt with the the YES / NO message box. In case you are not logged in as administrator it will prompt with a login dialog box which will ask you to enter an administrator credentials.

Comment: Yup I understand It Thank You